ReactJS - To determine if useEffect is necessary in the TableCellComponent
I am working on the ReactJS Project and I want to know if useEffect and useState in this case is necessary or if you have any logic explanation for this component:
I have component TableCellComponent that receive a value as props and this value can be primitive and non-primitive ,I use function to switch and then return the element. in this case is useEffect and useState is good solution or just using a function that render the element it sufficient ?
const TableCellComponent = ({ value }: { value: any }) => {
  const renderValue = (value: any) => {
    switch (value) {
      case typeof value === "number":
        return <h1>number</h1>;
      case typeof value === "object" && Array.isArray(value):
        return <h1>Array</h1>;
    }
  };

  return <td>{renderValue(value)}</td>;
};

export default TableCellComponent;



You are executing function renderValue just once inside individual TableCellComponent so you don't need useState because you are not updating anything within component and you are not doing network requests or something that needs asynchronous running to not block screen painting so you don't need useEffect either. I assume you update state from outside of component and when that state changes the component automatically re-renders with updated state.

This is what I understand, is when we need to update for example before displaying the value or like dealing with side effect I can use useState or useeffect.thx

useState is used to update values which will re-render a component

In my case , displaying the value using renderValue is the right solution ?. Thank you so much

Seems good for me
